# Read video using VideoReader function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing

I want to read a video from a folder and extract the frames from it.I used VidoeReader function.But it gives error.My code is shown below along with the error.

```
 mov=VideoReader('11.mp4');
 vidFrames=read(mov);
 nFrames=mov.NumberOfFrames;
 for i=1:nFrames
     imshow(vidFrames(:,:,i),[]);
 end
```

and the error show is as given below

Error using VideoReader/init
The file does not appear to have any video
data.

Error in VideoReader (line 147)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in video (line 7)
mov=VideoReader('11.mp4');

Comment: This question is specific to the movie file you are using, so it's difficult for us to help. Can you play the movie in a media player application? Does it have video content, or a still image, or just audio?

Comment: You will get an error later in your code. The relevant line should read: `imshow(vidFrames(:,:,:,i),[]);`

Comment: yes i am able to play the video in vlc player.the videoReader function can be used right?

Comment: Then I guess VideoReader either doesn't support the container (supposedly mpeg4, which it does support) or the video codec of that video. A solution is to use VLC to convert it to PNGs, then load these into MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a `MATLAB` version related problem. I faced the same problem when I was using `MATLAB 2013a`. However, when I changed to `MATLAB 2014b` the problem  just disappeared.